# List all dropdown elements with selenium

Tags: c#

I want to list all dropdown elements in datagridview rows one by one with selenium. I've had some attempts at this but it pulls the dropdown list twice. The first one lists all items on the same line. After the second line, it lists one element per line, exactly as I wanted. What am I doing wrong?

[image]

```
IList<IWebElement> selectElements = drv.FindElements(By.Id("ddlDersler"));
// Create DataTable outside the loop to avoid resetting it in each iteration
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
foreach (IWebElement select in selectElements)
{
    var selectElement = new SelectElement(select);

    //// Create a new column for each dropdown
    DataColumn dtcol = new DataColumn(select.Text);
    dt.Columns.Add(dtcol);

    // Create a new row for each option in the dropdown   // her satira dropdown çeken yer burasi
    foreach (IWebElement option in selectElement.Options)
    {
        DataRow row = dt.NewRow();
        row[select.Text] = option.Text.Trim();
        dt.Rows.Add(row);
    }
}
// Set the DataTable as the DataSource after the loop
dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try following code instead.

```
for (int i=1;i< selectElement.Options.Count;i++)
{
    DataRow row = dt.NewRow();
    row[select.Text] = selectElement.Options[i].Text.Trim();
    dt.Rows.Add(row);
}
```

Comment: It pulls all the courses into a single line in datagridview. I want each lesson to be drawn one by one, on a line.